# Customize xarray colorbar position

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I try to position colorbar in a designed position as figure below (horizontal in row 5, from second column onwards).

Here is demo code

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
# Make some random data
annual=xr.DataArray(np.random.randint(1,100,(41,186,469)), dims=("year","y","x"), coords={"year":np.arange(1981,2022),
                                                                                         "y":np.linspace(29,38,186),
                                                                                         "x":np.linspace(-10,10,469)})
# Plotting
proj=ccrs.PlateCarree()
fig=annual.plot(col="year",col_wrap=10, cmap="Spectral", vmin=1, vmax=105,
                subplot_kws={"projection":proj, "aspect":2.5})
# Increase title size
years=[f"Year = {i}" for i in range(1981,2022)]

for ax, year in zip(fig.axes.flatten(), years):
    ax.set_title(year,fontsize=15)
    ax.set_extent([-10, 10, 29, 38])
    ax.coastlines(linewidth=0.5)
    
fig.cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=30)
fig.cbar.set_label(label='Label', size=30, weight='bold')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is

```
fig = annual.plot(col="year", col_wrap=10, 
                  cmap="Spectral", vmin=1, vmax=105,
                  subplot_kws={"projection": proj, "aspect": 2.5},
                  cbar_kwargs={"location": "bottom"},
)
```